# Upload images to database (getting error Notice: Undefined index: image)

Tags: php

**Html file :**

```
<form action="cregister.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" id="wizForm">
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image" value="uploads/default.png" />
        <button type="button" id="simple-post" class="btn btn-success submitBtn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**action file :**

```
$filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$path = "uploads";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $path."/".$filename);
$photo = $path."/".$filename;


$insert = "INSERT INTO user (photo)VALUES ('$photo')";
$sth = $db->query($insert);
```

Getting error

`Notice:  Undefined index: image`

Comment: Have you made sure you're handling a POST request?

Comment: debug the result with `var_dump($_FILES)`

Comment: You need to get rid of the value attribute  from the input tag.

Comment: You should also insert a restriction / check for the acceptable image files (eg. jpg, png, bmp etc.) and also  restrict the size of the file.

Comment: tried wat u guys have commented....same result

Answer (score 2):

The file dose not take value this way, `value="uploads/default.png"`

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" value="uploads/default.png" />
```

You will need to select file and submit form

`print_r($_FILES)` in action file.

Comment: showing empty array                                               Array
(
)

Comment: did you click `browse` button and select file before submit form??

Comment: yes after uploading image have submitted it

Answer (score 0):

Try This

HTML

```
<html>
  <form action="cregister.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" id="wizForm">
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image" value="uploads/default.png" />
        <input type="submit" id="simple-post" class="btn btn-success submitBtn" value="Submit"/>
</form>  
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_FILES)){
        print_r($_FILES);
        $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $path = "uploads";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $path."/".$filename);
        $photo = $path."/".$filename;
    }
?>
```

Comment: not working man...database is empty...can u give me ur mail id ...vl send u complete code

Comment: rishikeshnlr@gmail.com

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp     
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php   For referrence you can go to these links